# Run function if last radio group change

Tags: jquery

I have a unknown radio button group and I want to run a function if a radio button of this group gets checked.

Is there something like `last-of-type` in jQuery that works with the following scenario ?

```
    <div class="variant--group">
      <div class="variant--option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio1">
      </div>
      <div class="variant--option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio1">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="variant--group">
      <div class="variant--option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio2">
      </div>
      <div class="variant--option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio2">
      </div>
    </div>

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this would be...

```
$(".variant--group").last().find(".radio").on("change", function() {
   //stuff here
});
```

Basically, get the groups, then pick the last one, then find radios inside of it and wait for a change to happen on them.

https://jsfiddle.net/omzgoo3k/

You could also select like this, `$(".variant--group:last .radio").on(...`

Answer (score 0):

The [last-of-type-selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/) has been added to jQuery V1.9 while the [:last selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector has beed added from jQuery V1.0.

The syntax:

**:radio.radio:last**

means: select last radio with class radio.

So, a possible solution can be:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.variant--group').find(':radio.radio:last').on('change', function(e) {
    $('body').append('<p>Last radio changed</p>');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="variant--group">
    <div class="variant--option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio1">
    </div>
    <div class="variant--option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="variant--group">
    <div class="variant--option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio2">
    </div>
    <div class="variant--option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to be only if the last radio is changed, OP was looking for any change in the last group of radios.

Comment: @smerny You are right, sorry for my first version. I'm trying to improve my knowledge. Thanks so much.

Comment: Now you are finding if they selected the last radio in any group, rather than any radio in the last group.